# how to get the angle of movement (direction) of a car when using VeinsInetMobility

Tags: omnet++, veins, inet

I need to get the angle of movement (direction) of a node.

In  `TraCIMobility` this is done with `getHeading()` in veins-5 and with `getAngleRad()` in the previous versions of veins

But I can't figure out what is the equivalent of `getHeading()` when using `VeinsInetMobility`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veins 5 `VeinsInetMobility` (for INET 4) is based on `inet::MobilityBase` which, in turn, implements `inet::IMobility` (see https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/blob/v4.2.0/src/inet/mobility/contract/IMobility.h). This interface offers `getCurrentVelocity` which returns a vector. Its magnitude is the speed of the vehicle, its angles are the direction.